# None of my React Components are loading inside of my html.erb files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I have this error in my browser dev tools "Calling Element.createShadowRoot() for an element which already hosts a shadow root is deprecated," which I suspect may be the issue. I also suspect that installing babel may have messed up my react-rendering, or possible the fact that I removed all my npm packages. Inside of the body tags on the browser, I have 
< div data react-class="Home"> < /div>, but nothing shows up on the page. I'm using react-rails gem.

**Inside my root html.erb file** 
< %= react_component ('Home') % >

**My Home Component**

class Home extends React.Component {

render() {

return()
< div>

< h1>  Hello < /h1>

< /div>

}

**Inside my application.js**

//= require jquery

//= require jquery_ujs

//= require react

//= require react_ujs

//= require components

//= require_tree .

**Inside my components.js**

//= require_tree ./components

Comment: Can you please add some actual code, like the js file and template file that has the react hook in it

Comment: Well hang on, there is an error stating `Calling Element.createShadowRoot() for an element which already hosts a shadow root is deprecated`. Did this appear at point of writing your render()? Make sure you're exporting as well with `export default` at the start of your class.

Comment: There might be some errors in your code, but it's hard to tell because it's not formatted and I'm not sure if anything was lost when pasting. [this markdown guide](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) could help.

Comment: @Dandy-  I believe export default is for a standalone React App, not react-rails. Also, The Calling Element.createShadowRoot() error is not caused by render(), I commented it out, and it is still there. -tompave - I didn't lose anything when pasting I believe.

Answer (score 0):

your return statement isn't correct, try:

```
  render() {
    return ( 
      <div>   
        <h1>Hello</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Don't forget to delete the space in your html tags right after "<".

Answer (score 0):

There is problem in your render code. It must look like this :-

```
return ( the tags and html part will come here );
```

So after correction it will look like this :- (dont forget ; too)

```
render()
{
        return(
        < div>
        < h1> Hello < /h1>
        < /div>
        );
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks